# create dict with keys from matrix rows in form {row:[col, value]}

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Given a list of lists, `matrix` (row j and column k, element value) I can make a flattened list of the values with the list-comprehension:

```
matrix = [['00','01','02'],['10','11','12'],['20','21','22']]
list_1  = [value for (j,row) in enumerate(matrix) for (k,value) in enumerate(row)]
print(list_1)
#output: ['00', '01', '02', '10', '11', '12', '20', '21', '22']
```

which mimics nested for-loop syntax:

```
list_2 = []
for (j,row) in enumerate(matrix):
    for (k,value) in enumerate(row):
        list_2.append(value)
```

If I wanted a dictionary of for entries of form {j:[k,value]}, what is the equivalent dict comprehension syntax, and why doesn't using a curly braced equivalent work? e.g.:

```
list_3  = {j:[k,value] for (j,row) in enumerate(matrix) for (k,value) in enumerate(row)}

#expected output: {0:[0,'00'], 0:[1,'01'], 0:[2,'02']...}
#actual output: {0: [2, '02'], 1: [2, '12'], 2: [2, '22']}
```

Comment: why to use `enumerate` in the first example?

Comment: please provide example of input and desired output for `dict` case

Comment: Try `a_list = [ {j:[k,value]} for (j,row) in ...]`

Comment: Take a look at [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), and as @AzatIbrakov says, please provide example input & output.

Comment: @user55449 I should have mentioned: this is for python 2.7, and I know that dict comprehensions have been evolving from earlier versions...

Comment: All keys in a dictionary must be unique. In your case, there will be `k` elements with the same keys (since each row `j` will have `k` columns), thus all except last element with that key will be deleted. One suggestion could be to make the key: `(j,k)`

Comment: @nikpod yes, you are right.  The reason I wanted a row dict was that I need fast lookup by row value for any column; this is broken with a (frankly nicer) key `(j,k)`.  Maybe you have a suggestion for this usecase?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it's not necessary for the list, but in the dict I'm trying to create I wanted to add the indices to the key/value pairs.  Just trying to keep syntax parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres nothing wrong with your code. Dict keys are meant to be unique and duplicate keys are not possible in Dictionaries, since the reference is the same key in the dict comprehension the data will be replaced as you can see in your actual output.You can use the code in this way

```
matrix = [['00','01','02'],['10','11','12'],['20','21','22']]
a_list  = {j:row for (j,row) in enumerate(matrix)}
for key,value in a_list.items():
    new_list = {}
    for i,j in enumerate(value):
        new_list[i]=j
    a_list[key] = new_list
a_list
```

Output:

```
{0: {0: '00', 1: '01', 2: '02'},
 1: {0: '10', 1: '11', 2: '12'},
 2: {0: '20', 1: '21', 2: '22'}}
```

or

```
matrix = [['00','01','02'],['10','11','12'],['20','21','22']]
a_list  = {j:row for (j,row) in enumerate(matrix)}
for key,value in a_list.items():
    new_list = []
    for i,j in enumerate(value):
        new_list.append([i,j])
    a_list[key] = new_list
a_list
```

Output:

```
{0: [[0, '00'], [1, '01'], [2, '02']],
 1: [[0, '10'], [1, '11'], [2, '12']],
 2: [[0, '20'], [1, '21'], [2, '22']]}
```

Comment: This is correct.  However, I want fast lookup by row values, so a tuple key won't be useful; is there a way to get the collection of elements with a given row value short of nested dicts?

Comment: Cant you just add the whole row for that key?